# Как сворачивать меню в мобильной версии сайта при нажатии на пукт меню?

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Есть рабочее меню для адаптивного лэндинга. Хочу, чтобы в мобильной версии, при выборе пункта меню, меню автоматически сворачивалось. В данный момент чтобы свернуть нужно опять нажать на иконку. Помогите пожалуйста. Впал в "кому":)

```
<nav class="clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#advantages">Преимущества</a></li>
        <li><a href="#characters">Характеристики</a></li>
        <li><a href="#garantie">Гарантии</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sale">Акция</a></li>
        <li><a href="#complect">Комплектация</a></li>
        <li><a href="#review">Отзывы</a></li>   
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="pull">Меню</a>
</nav><!-- END nav -->
```

и стили

```
nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #2E3192;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2E3192;
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 40px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}
nav li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #8c99a4; 
}
nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}


/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {

    nav {
        border-bottom: 0;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
        nav li {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
        nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-indent: 25px;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        background-color: #2E3192;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
        content:"";
        background: url('../images/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
    }
}
```

скрипт

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('nav ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Если вам подошёл какой-либо из ответов, отметьте его галочкой, чтобы остальные знали, что это решение работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#pull, nav ul a').on('click', function(e) {
    if($(window).width()<900) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Уже ответил вам, но все-таки продублирую ответ.
в скрипте замените строчку:

```
$(pull).on('click', function(e) {
```

на такую:

```
$('#pull, nav ul a').on('click', function(e) {
```

Comment: вчера не заметил. а вот дело в том что меню исчезает не только в мобильной версии! тоесть не меню, а пункты меню